# Get an array of unique product attributes/values with the highest price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, price

In WooCommerce, I would like to:

1. Get the unique values for a certain product attribute (From all my products), *assuming all products have that particular attribute set as something.*
2. Get the list of unique attribute values with the highest product price.

**For Example:**

Product 1: 
Product-Attribute = Green  
Price = $100

Product 2:  
Product-Attribute = Red  
Price = $50

Product 3:  
Product-Attribute = Green  
Price = $50

> **Expected result (an array):**
>
> Green : $100 
> Red : $50

Any ideas on how to code this so that it returns an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Variable products and its variation attributes name and term value name with the highest variation price in an array, you will try the following custom function:

```
function get_variations_attributes_values_highest_price(){
    global $wpdb;

    // SQL query
    $all_attributes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies");
    $product_attributes = array();
    foreach( $all_attributes as $value ){
        $product_attributes = 'pa_'.$value->attribute_name;
    }
    //$pa_taxonomies = "'".implode("','", $product_attributes)."'";

    // The 2nd SQL query
    $query = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT p.ID, pm.meta_key as attr, pm.meta_value as term, pm2.meta_value as price
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type IN ('product_variation','product')
        AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_pa_%'
        AND pm2.meta_key LIKE '_price'
        AND pm2.meta_value != ''
        ORDER BY pm.meta_key ASC, pm.meta_value ASC, CAST(replace(pm2.meta_value, 'MDT ', '') AS UNSIGNED) ASC
    " );
    //print_pr($query);

    $ordered_results = $results = array();

    // Loop 1: Filtering and removing duplicate terms keeping highest price
    foreach( $query as $values ){
        if( !empty($values->price)){
        $filter_key = $values->attr .' '.$values->term;
            $ordered_results[$filter_key] = (object) array( 'attr' => $values->attr,
                'term' => $values->term, 'price' => $values->price );
        }
    }

    // Loop 2: Get the real name values, formatting data
    foreach( $ordered_results as $result ){
        $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_' , '', $result->attr );
        $attr_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name; // Attribute name
        $value_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $result->term, $taxonomy )->name; // Attribute value term name
        $results[$attr_name.' - '.$value_name] = wc_price($result->price);
    }
    return $results; 
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

---

```
## --- USAGE --- ##

// RAW ARRAY OUTPUT
echo '<pre>'; print_r(get_variations_attributes_values_highest_price()); echo '</pre>';
```

You can make little changes easily to match your needs *(the honey for TheBear)*…